# exoplayer is working well but null player in service

Tags: android

I use exoplayer in service for background streaming. And I found something strange. When I get the player at activity, the player is null. But the music is streaming and I can hear that song. Why the player in service is null even though it's streaming? I don't understand this. For example, If I click the musicOnOff Button, I get the null point error of player, but the music is streaming. please let me understand this...

*error*

```
kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException
```

*Activity*

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private var mBound = false
    var mIntent = Intent()
    var audioService :AudioService ?= null
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        audioService = AudioService()
        mIntent = Intent(this,AudioService::class.java)
        Util.startForegroundService(this,mIntent)

        binding.musicOnOffButton.setOnClickListener {
            initializePlayer()
        }

    }

    private fun initializePlayer() {
        if (mBound) {
            val player: SimpleExoPlayer = audioService!!.getplayerInstance()!!
            binding.musicPlayer.player = player
            binding.musicPlayer.useController = true
        }
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        bindService(mIntent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE)
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        unbindService(mConnection)
    }

    private val mConnection: ServiceConnection = object : ServiceConnection {
        override fun onServiceConnected(componentName: ComponentName, iBinder: IBinder) {
            mBound = true
            //initializePlayer()
        }

        override fun onServiceDisconnected(componentName: ComponentName) {

        }
    }

}
```

*Service*

```
class AudioService  : Service() {
    private val mBinder: IBinder =Binder()
    var player: SimpleExoPlayer? = null
    private var cacheDataSourceFactory : CacheDataSourceFactory?=null
    var mContext: Context? = null
    lateinit var notification : Notification

    override fun onDestroy() {
        releasePlayer()
        super.onDestroy()
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        Log.d("TAG","TAG : onCreate")

    }

    private fun releasePlayer() {
        if (player != null) {
            player!!.release()
            player = null
        }
    }

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder {
        return mBinder
    }

    fun getplayerInstance(): SimpleExoPlayer? {
        if (player == null) {
            startPlayer(mContext!!)
        }
        return player
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        Log.d("TAG","TAG : onStartCommand")
        mContext = this
        startPlayer(mContext!!)
        val myNotificationListener = object :MyNotificationListener{
            override fun onPlay() {
                player!!.playWhenReady= !player!!.playWhenReady
            }

            override fun onRemove() {
                stopSelf()
                //stopForeground(true)
            }
        }

        val receiver = NotificationBroadCast(myNotificationListener)
        registerReceiver(receiver, IntentFilter("TRACKS_TRACKS"))
        createNotification(
            this,
            MusicTrack("title 1","artist 1",R.drawable.reaction_happy),
            1,
            3
        )
        startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID,notification)

        return START_STICKY
    }

    private fun startPlayer(context: Context) {
        val uri: Uri = Uri.parse("https://storage.googleapis.com/exoplayer-test-media-0/Jazz_In_Paris.mp3")
        player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(context, DefaultTrackSelector())

        cacheDataSourceFactory = getCacheDataSourceFactory(context)
        val mediaSource: MediaSource = ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(cacheDataSourceFactory)
            .createMediaSource(uri)
        player!!.prepare(mediaSource)
        player!!.setPlayWhenReady(true)
    }

    fun getCacheDataSourceFactory(context : Context) : CacheDataSourceFactory?{
        if(cacheDataSourceFactory==null){
            cacheDataSourceFactory = CacheDataSourceFactory(
                context,
                DefaultDataSourceFactory(context, "ua"),
                MyExoPlayer.MAX_CACHE_VALUE, MyExoPlayer.MAX_CACHE_FILE_VALUE
            )
        }
        return cacheDataSourceFactory
    }
    fun createNotification(context: Context, musicTrack: MusicTrack,  pos:Int, size:Int){

        val notificationManager = context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        val resultIntent = Intent(context, MobileActivity::class.java)
        resultIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP)
        val resultPendingIntent: PendingIntent? = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0,resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT)

        var previousIntent :PendingIntent ?=null
        var nextIntent :PendingIntent ?=null
        var playIntent :PendingIntent ?=null

        var image_prev = 0
        var image_next = 0

        if(pos==0){
            previousIntent = null
            image_prev =0
        }else{
            val intentPrevious = Intent(context,
                NotificationReceiver::class.java).setAction(
                MusicNotification.ACTION_PREVIOUS
            )
            previousIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,0,intentPrevious,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
            image_prev = R.drawable.play_previous
        }

        if(pos==size){
            nextIntent = null
            image_next =0
        }else{
            val intentNext = Intent(context,
                NotificationReceiver::class.java).setAction(
                MusicNotification.ACTION_NEXT
            )
            nextIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,0,intentNext,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
            image_next = R.drawable.play_next
        }

        val intentPlay = Intent(context,
            NotificationReceiver::class.java).setAction(
            MusicNotification.ACTION_PLAY
        )
        playIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,0,intentPlay,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)

        val intentCancel = Intent(context,
            NotificationReceiver::class.java).setAction(
            MusicNotification.ACTION_PLAY
        )
        val cancelIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,0,intentCancel,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)

        var binding = CustomNotificationBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context))

        var contentView = RemoteViews(context.packageName, R.layout.custom_notification)
        contentView.setTextViewText(binding.notiMusicName.id,musicTrack.title)
        contentView.setOnClickPendingIntent(binding.prevButton.id,previousIntent)
        contentView.setOnClickPendingIntent(binding.startButton.id,playIntent)
        contentView.setOnClickPendingIntent(binding.nextButton.id,nextIntent)


        notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.music_note)
            .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
            .setShowWhen(false)
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContent(contentView)
            .setCustomContentView(contentView)
            .setCustomBigContentView(contentView)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
            .setColorized(true)
            .setColor(context.getColor(R.color.colorPrimary))
            .build()



        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
            val channelName ="Music Channel"
            val channel = NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID,channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT)
            channel.enableLights(true)
            channel.lightColor= 0x00FFFF
            channel.setShowBadge(false)
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
        }
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this. because of my insufficient  understanding about service and binder, I can't get the result I want.

I added Local Binder that point the current Service

*added in AudioService*

```
    val mBinder: IBinder = LocalBinder()

    inner class LocalBinder : Binder() {
        val service: AudioService
            get() = this@AudioService
    }
```

*added In MainActivity*

```
    private val mConnection: ServiceConnection = object : ServiceConnection {
        override fun onServiceConnected(componentName: ComponentName, iBinder: IBinder) {
            mBound = true
            val binder = iBinder as AudioService.LocalBinder
            audioService = binder.service
            initializePlayer()
        }

        override fun onServiceDisconnected(componentName: ComponentName) {

        }
    }
```